# External javascript file not executing

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

The problem is that the following external javascript file is not executing:

```
<script src="//www.google-analytics.com/cx/api.js?experiment=YOUR_EXPERIMENT_ID"></script>
```

When I access the URL directly it downloads the file as f.txt

And when I copy/paste the content from the file then it's fully functional js and working as it should: creating `cxApi` object.

Got the snippet from: https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/experiments-client-side

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser console?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are testing using a local file.

i.e. the URL in your browser's address bar is something like `file:///Users/you/Desktop/test.html`

The relative URL `//www.google-analytics.com/cx/api.js?experiment=YOUR_EXPERIMENT_ID` then resolves to `file://www.google-analytics.com/cx/api.js?experiment=YOUR_EXPERIMENT_ID`, which does not exist.

You may see an error in the Console of your browser's developer tools. You should see one in the Network tab.

**Test using a web server. Access your pages over HTTP**

Then you will have something like `http://localhost/test.html`, and the URL will resolve to `http://www.google-analytics.com/cx/api.js?experiment=YOUR_EXPERIMENT_ID`, which does exist.

Comment: Nope, not testing locally. Try opening the URL yourself www.google-analytics.com/cx/api.js - does it show the content or downloads the f.txt file?

Comment: It downloads the t.txt file … but that doesn't mean anything significant. The file contains the JS and it won't download if accessed through a `<script>` tag.

Comment: Network tab: status 307, size 0kb - right click and open in new tab downloads the same txt file

Comment: @SilverRingvee — that's a redirect. The browser should follow the redirect automatically.

Comment: so what's the action here? btw the site is: https://reflectivedata.com/

Comment: @SilverRingvee — It appears to be working fine there. You don't seem to have a problem. (Do you have any privacy enforcing plugins set up in your browser? They'll generally block GA stuff.)

Comment: Nope. no plugins related to privacy and everything other related to GA is fine in. Works for me on Firefox (first tested in Chrome). That's an issue if the code doesn't load for visitors either...